# Why is sys.dm_exec_connection.connect_time later than sys.dm_exec_sessions.login_time for user processes for some cases?

Tags: sql-server, dmv

I executed the query on my production server.

```
select  s.session_id, 
        s.login_time,
        s.is_user_process, 
        c.session_id, 
        c.connect_time, 
        case when c.Connect_Time <=s.login_time then 1 else 0 end AS is_connect_time_earlier_than_login_time
from sys.dm_exec_connections AS c  
 JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s on s.session_id = c.session_id
```

Here is the snippet of the output.

session_id  login_time  is_user_process session_id  connect_time    is_connect_time_earlier_than_login_time

167 2018-01-18 20:27:14.330 1   167 2018-01-18 20:12:50.747 1

171 2018-01-18 20:12:57.340 1   171 2018-01-18 20:12:57.347 0

Is there an explanation whey the 2nd row shows that the connect_time is later than the login_time ? OR is it a case of the reported time resolution not being too good in the millisecond range ?

Comment: Given the limited information, a best guess would be something to do with connection pooling. Is there a problem, or are you just curious?